# Trying to get 2 animations to work simultaneously

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewanimation, caanimation

In the next code there are 2 methods that are called one after the other. The first one makes the center button disappear and the second one makes the tabbar disappear. Separately they are working fine. 
My problem is that when I try to call them one after the other `hideCenterButton` doesn't animate. Instead of rolling to the left of the screen the button just disappears.

```
-(void)hideCenterButton:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(animated){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             CGRect frame = self.centerButton.frame;
                             frame.origin.x = -100;
                             self.centerButton.frame = frame;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         }];
    }}
```

...

```
- (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        //[UIView setAnimationDelay:1];
        for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
            else
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
            }
        }

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Comment: Don't misuse the x-code tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably hit into some kind of limitation of UIView-based animations. Several things you might try are:

1. use `animateWithDuration` also for `hideTabBar:`: indeed, `beginAnimation` is the old-way of animating UIView; animateWithDuration is more recent (introduced with iOS4); by using the same animation calls in bot cases you might get better results; this should be straightforward; this should work:

   ```
     - (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
     {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         delay:0.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                    animations:^{
       for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
       {
       if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
       {
           [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
       }
       else
       {
           [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
       }
      }
                    }
                    completion:nil];
   }
   ```
2. rewrite your animation using Core Animation: this is a slightly lower-level mechanism but it allows you to get the best results in terms of performance; this is, e.g., how you could rewrite the first animation:

first you need to provide a callback:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CABasicAnimation*)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
       CALayer* layer = [anim valueForKey:@"animationLayer"];
       layer.position = [anim.toValue CGPointValue];
}
```

then you can animate your button like this:

```
    CABasicAnimation* move = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    CGPoint pos = self.centerButton.center;
    pos.x -= 100;
    move.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pos];
    move.duration = 0.3;
    move.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    move.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    move.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    move.autoreverses = NO;
    move.delegate = self;
    [move setValue:self.centerButton.layer forKey:@"animationLayer"];
    [self.centerButton.layer addAnimation:move forKey:@"buttonPosition"];
```

Using Core Animation, you will end up writing more code and you will need to allow some time to learn Core Animation basics, but that was the only way I could solve a similar issue I had with two related animation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have no idea how to convert `hideTabBar` to `animateWithDuration` but I'll definitely read about Core animation.

Comment: I have added some more code as an example, including for `animateWithDuration`.

Comment: The first solution doesn't change anything but I've learned something new so +1 just for that. :). I'm trying the second solution but I get an error for the last 2 rows (obviously). What should I put there instead of `subview`?

Comment: Yea, figured that out. For some reason that doesn't animate, just changed the center button position.

Comment: ok, then try my edit; it is likely that the animation will occur now but your button bar will be unresponsive after that -- this is because you should set the final button position in a `animationDidStop:` delegate call...  I will add the code for that in a couple of seconds...

Comment: sorry... copy/paste gone wild...  this should be the signature for the callback: `  - (void)animationDidStop:(CABasicAnimation*)anim finished:(BOOL)flag`

Comment: I'm still getting `Assigning to 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') from incompatible type 'id'`

Comment: sorry again. this should be the last one: `layer.position = [anim.toValue CGPointValue];` -- what would be my life without a compiler? :-)

Comment: Perfect!!!!!!!!!!!! Without `animationDidStop` everything worked and the tabbar WAS responsive but I got the same results as before. Only the first animation worked. Now that `animationDidStop` is working it's really smooth. Please explain me what `animationDidStop` does :)

Comment: nothing special, you see: it sets the final button position. otherwise, you can freeze the animation (like I suggested to do setting `removedOnCompletion` to YES) in its final state, but apparently that "freeze" is not good for the rest of the animations... without setting `removedOnCompletion` to YES (first attempt), the animation was done but the button got back to its initial position... in any case: last version is the correct (although lengthier) one, so no surprise it works better...

Comment: Another question if I may. Why when I try to show the center button after it was hidden, I only change `pos.y -= 100;` in the code but I get a much bigger and unscaled button picture? Edit: I think I know why. For some reason the `hideTab` method is screwing around with the scale of the image. I have no idea why.

Comment: It's not for sure, your code works perfectly. This question is too full already. I've posted the new problem in a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033373/animation-is-causing-an-image-to-stretch#comment19385401_14033373