# Animation is causing an image to stretch

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've taken the day to try to understand animations better.
The next code works great and hides my tabbar. The problem is that it will stretch every UIButton that is near it. Including a custom button on the tab bar. If it touches another layer of image it will stretch it. Any idea how I can fix the code to avoid that? Thanks

```
 - (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
  {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    }
    else
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
    }
   }
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

[image]

**After hide:**

[image]

Comment: You should go ahead and describe in more detail what you actually want - sometimes a quickly drafted image does wonders.

Comment: New pics are added. The repo will be added in a few secs.

Comment: A link with the program has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `UIButton` and not a `UIImageView`. From the screenshot it is obvious that it is going to else part for this button.

So you need to modify you if condition as,

```
if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
```

and then set the frame. Similarly change your show method as well.

Comment: The solution works but when I want to show the tabbar again the center button doesn't come back to the same position. Edit: When I click on Hide I can see the center button leveling up to the same hight as the tabbar. Have no idea why.

Comment: @Sha, That is why I said, you need to handle it in show method as well. Add an if condition only with `if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]` and set the frame accordingly.

Comment: With your solution I can use simple animations with out stretching so I used an animation to give the button a little boost on the way up and now it works great. I might try the if condition fix just for kicks. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to use it inside animation blocks. That's what I meant. I just mentioned that the if condition you used earlier is wrong. It is a UIButton and not a UIImageView. That is the actual issue. Anyways Good to know that it is fixed now. :)